# Pass values from AJAx to PHP

Tags: php, ajax

```
function get_menu_list(){
        var val=10;
        $.ajax({
            url:'action/kkk.php',
            type:'POST',
            data:{val:val},
            contentType:false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            //dataType:"json",
            beforeSend:function(){
            },
            success:function(data){
                
            },
            
        });
    }
```

> kkk.Php. I want the $val which received from ajax and pass it into database Limit but seem not work, any thing wrong?

```
$val =$_POST['val'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbe_pro ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,".$val."";
```

Comment: How did you try to debug? Have you tried to return the variable val?

Comment: set method to 'POST' not type.